# Control remote Bluetooth music playback with Ubuntu

Tags: bluetooth, music, a2dp, blueman

I have a Bluetooth speaker, and when I connect it to my tablet, I am able to control music playback with the buttons on the speaker. With Windows as well, a little "music player" shows up when music from the tablet is playing through the computer's speakers. Is that possible with Ubuntu? I am able to play music through A2DP by using *blueman*, but I can't control the playback without reaching for the tablet.